# Add users to an AD group by distinguished name

Tags: active-directory, user-management

I have a multi-forest AD environment with trust relationships between domains in different forests. (AD level 2003)

I have a list of distinguishednames of users that I want to add to a local group in one of those domains.

How can I add a user to a group from the command line using the users DN?  I can easily automate this with such a command and avoid having to do several hundred manual add commands though the GUI, but I can't find the command to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dsmod group` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732423(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

dsmod looks the simplest solution, but you can do it with a simple VBScript script. See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/ad/groups/default.mspx?mfr=true for lots of examples.

JR